# Showing a subset of $l^{\infty}$ is totally bounded

Tags: analysis, compactness

Consider $l^{\infty}$ (space of bounded real sequences) equipped with the norm $||x||=\sup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}(x_n)$. I'm trying to show that the subset
$$A = \{(a_n) \in l^{\infty} , |a_n|\leq\frac{1}{2^n}  \}$$ compact. We know that $l^{\infty}$ is complete with respect to this norm, so I'm trying to show $A$ is totally bounded. Following a [similar tactic to an answer to this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217454/compact-subsets-in-l-infty-converse-of-my-last-question), this is what I have so far,

First recall that closed and bounded subsets of $\mathbb{R}^k$ are compact, and hence totally bounded. Now fix $\epsilon >0$ and $N \in \mathbb{N}$ so that for $n > N$, $\frac{1}{2^n}<\epsilon$. Now $[-\frac{1}{2^n},\frac{1}{2^n}]$ is totally bounded, say by $b_1,...,b_l$. That is,

$$[-\frac{1}{2^n},\frac{1}{2^n}]^k \subseteq \bigcup_{j=1}^lB_{\epsilon}(b_j) $$

Now let $c_j = (b_j,0,0,...)$. Clearly $c_j \in l^{\infty}$.

My claim is that $A$ is totally bounded by $\epsilon$ radius balls around the $c_j$, however I'm a bit stuck with the technicality of showing that this is true. Ie. how do I show for an arbitrary $x \in A$ that $x$ is in one of the $c_j$? As a set, I can consider any sequence in $A$ to be finite since they are bounded and strictly decreasing and hence convergent, but that doesn't give me a maximum value for $k$ to fit every sequence as a vector in $[-\frac{1}{2^n},\frac{1}{2^n}]^k$. Perhaps that's the wrong way to think about it?

Would appreciate any tips.

Thanks.

Comment: $A$ isn't closed. How could it be compact?  As for totally bounded: Say $a = (\alpha, a_{n+1}, \dotsc)\in A$ has the prefix $\alpha$ of length $n$, and the same for $b=(\beta, b_{n+1},\dotsc)\in A$. Then, we have $\|a-b\| \le \|\alpha -\beta\| + \frac 2 {2^{n+1}}$.

Comment: Sorry typo, the bound should be $\leq$.

Comment: Been playing around with it for a while and I still can't see how that inequality gives total boundedness precisely? @user251257

Answer (score 0):

Let $\|\cdot\|$ denote the supremum norm on $\mathbb R^n$ and $l^\infty$. Further, for $n\in\mathbb N$ let
$$ A_n = \prod_{i=1}^n \left[ -2^{-i}, 2^{-i} \right] $$
and
$$ \tilde A_n = \prod_{i=n+1}^\infty \left[ -2^{-i}, 2^{-i} \right]. $$
That is $A = A_n \times \tilde A_n$.

Let $\epsilon > 0$ and $\delta=\epsilon /2$.

1. Let $n$ with $2^{-(n+1)} \le \delta$ and $b_1,\dotsc, b_l\in\mathbb R^n$ with 
   $$ A_n \subseteq \bigcup_{j=1} B_\delta(b_j). $$
2. Now, fix some $z=(x,y)\in A_n \times \tilde A_n = A$.
3. Then, there exists some $j_0$ with $x\in B_\delta(b_{j_0})$. Thus, we have
   $$ \| z - c_{j_0} \| \le \| x - b_{j_0} \| + \| y\| < \delta + \delta = \epsilon. $$
   That is, $z\in B_\epsilon(c_{j_0})$ for $c_{j_0} = (b_{j_0}, 0,\dotsc)$.